# Jquery session Lifetime

Tags: asp.net, master-pages, jquery-session

I am stroring the selected link id in the session. I want to read this session after page gets opened to hi-light that link. But the session gets cleared.

Code:

```
      $("div.menu_body a").click(function() {               
            $.session("ActiveLink", "#A3");
            alert($.session("ActiveLink"));---------> Has id                        

      });
    alert($.session("ActiveLink"));-----------> Undefiened
```

Problem:
 **i am not getting this session value outside that event.**

Geetha

Comment: Is this being opened in the same window, or a new tab/window?

Comment: It will open in the same window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vars are lost in the page is open in another window or tab. - Objects with functions can't be stored - Window.name is lost - Only Strings can be stored